# I'm getting this error while installing hardhat -> Cannot find module '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox

Tags: node.js, ethereum, hardhat

[hardhat-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDNeI.png)

tried npm install --save-dev hardhat
and then did npx hardhat to check if it was installed peoperly but it's not working
checked both 'hardhat-config-js' and
'package.json' for nomicfoundation dependencies and it is there but still I'm getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You should be running on windows. Run the following command.

npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox